# What do you call a colleague under you in the organisations structure?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm after a word that best describes a person that works under someone else.

For example, I had a joke with my manager saying that I have to do his bidding because I'm his **subordinate**. We laughed, then later thought what is the actual word for this relationship with a manager? Subordinate seems a little harsh for the context.

For context you could call this a standard office type work environment.

**Edit**: I'm in the UK.

Comment: Believe it or not, *subordinate* is the word that best describes someone who works under someone else. I'd say it sounds more like a technical term rather than something harsh.

Comment: thought it was gofer.

Comment: I remember hearing the term _reportee_ but am not able to find an online reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a **subordinate** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subordinate)

> Subject to the authority or control of another

And likely in this org you have those *superior* to you.

Comment: Someone of higher rank than you is *senior* to you. *Superior to* is also used, but it might be misunderstood, because it also means "better than".

Comment: @RosieF By that logic, senior could also be misunderstood, because it also means "older than".

Comment: @RosieF superior as a noun is [less ambiguous (link to dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/superior).

Comment: "Subordinate", other than in a formal register, is outmoded. It has no direct replacement, but people say things like "John works for/reports to Fred" - or "Fred is his line manager".

Answer (score 1):

A little less formally, you could describe yourself as a **'member of his team'**. He is the team leader, so the team belongs to *him*. It’s a little tongue-in-cheek when there are only two members of the team in total.

Other alternatives (ranging in colloquialism).
You are his

- sidekick (like Batman and Robin)
- lackey
- henchman
- junior (because he is senior to you)
- underling
- assistant
- deputy